# Address sanitizer is not working with application which is using rocksdb

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, rocksdb

I am using rocksdb 4.13 version in a c++ project. To find memory issue I wanted to use libasan. But I could not test my application as it exits before running any test. It mostly points to `rocksdb::DB::Open` and `rocksdb-4.13/db/db_impl_open.cc`. Is there any work around to use libasan with application linked to rocksdb ?

Comment: Did you compile rocksdb with `-fsanitize=address`?

Comment: Yes, I used -fsanitize=address to compile and -lasan to link.

Comment: @Halder "-lasan to link" - the recommended way is to use `-fsanitize=address` when linking as well (`-lasan` alone is not enough for proper linking).

Answer (score 3):

> But I could not test my application as it exits before running any test.

If you want your ASAN instrumented binary/application to continue run after reporting first error, then compile it with `-fsanitize-recover=address` and then run your application with `ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0`, like this:

```
# ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0 <application_binary_name>
```

You can also embed flags in the source code by implementing `__asan_default_options` function, like this:

```
const char *__asan_default_options() {
    return "halt_on_error=0";
}
```

This can be used in case when your application is started by, say, some startup script or some other daemon etc.